Meromorphic function with a pole of modulus $r$ has a pole at $z=r$
I was reading Berkeley Problems in Mathematics and I'm stumped on problem 5.8.32
Problem. Let $f$ be a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ which is analytic in a neighborhood of 0. Let it's Maclaurin series be
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k
\label{e1}
\end{equation}
with all $a_k\geq 0$. Suppose there is a pole of modulus $r>0$ and no pole has modulus $<r$. Prove there is a pole at $z=r$.
Proof. w.l.o.g. assume $r=1$, otherwise work with $g(z)=f(rz)$. Since there is no pole inside the unit circle the radius of convergence of \eqref{e1} is 1. If $f$ is analytic at 1, then it has a power series expansion with a positive radius of convergence, so the series expansion of $f$ centered at $1/2$ has radius $1/2+\epsilon$, for some $\epsilon>0$. See here for a draw.
We have $$f^{(n)}(1/2) = \sum_{k\geq n}\frac{k!}{(k-n)!}a_k\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-n},$$
so for $x\in (1,1+\epsilon)$
\begin{align}
f(x)&= \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{f^{(n)}(1/2)}{n!}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\\
&=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n!}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\sum_{k\geq n}\frac{k!}{(k-n)!}a_k\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-n}\\
&=\sum_{k\geq n\geq 0}a_k\frac{k!}{n!(k-n)!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-n}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\\
&=\sum_{k\geq 0}a_k\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{k!}{n!(k-n)!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-n}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k
\end{align}
A contradiction since \eqref{e1} diverges for $|z|>1$, therefore $f$ has a pole at $z=1$.
My problem is, why doesn't this work for any other point in the unit circle? Assume $f$ analytic at $e^{it}$, it has an expansion with positive radius, then the expansion at $e^{it}/2$ has radius $1/2+\epsilon$ and, doing similar algebraic manipulations, coincides with \eqref{e1}, in particular \eqref{e1} is valid for a point outside the unit circle which is a contradiction. This would mean that $f$ is not analytic in the whole unit circle which can't happen since the poles are all isolated singularities. Does this have to do with the coeficients of \eqref{e1} being non negative, or is the book's proof wrong? Either way I can't see why.

the problem is that what you prove is the Pringsheim-Landau theorem, namely that if $f(z)=\sum a_n z^n$ has radius of convergence $1$ and $a_n \ge 0$ then $1$ is a singularity of $f$ but that doesn't mean that $1$ is a pole - you have to use the hypothesis that $f$ has a pole on the convergence circle; since the only singularities of $f$ are poles then you are done

also your comment about $e^{it}$ ignores the fact that the derivatives $f^{(n)}(e^{it}/2) $ are generally not positive numbers anymore so you cannot switch double sums with impunity anymore; check $\frac{1}{1-z}$ for example

@Conrad by hypothesis $f$ is meromorphic, so its only singularities are poles. Your second comment answers my questions tough, since the terms in the series are all positives and we're assuming it converges, then it does so absolutely so I can change the summation order, hence the result. Thanks for naming the theorem as well.

The key is we need to use $a_k \geq 0$.
Key Theorem: If a complex series converges absolutely, then it converges.
The contrapositive of this is that if a complex series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k$ diverges, so does $\sum_{k=0}^\infty |b_k|$.
Suppose that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ diverges for some $z$ of modulus $1$.
Then it diverges absolutely, so $\sum_{k=0}^\infty |a_kz^k| = \sum_{k=0}^\infty |a_k| = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ diverges, which is the desired contradiction. Note we use $a_k \geq 0$ in the last step.
As @Conrad pointed out in a comment, this only shows, combined with what you already had, that $f$ is not analytic at $z=1$. We need to show that it is a pole, specifically. But $f$ is assumed to be meromorphic, so this point is moot.

and how does that imply that there is a pole at 1? note that $-\log (1-z)=\sum z^n/n$ satisfies $a_n \ge 0$ but doesn't have a pole at $1$; you need to also use the hypothesis that there is a pole on the unit circle somewhere, the divergence of $\sum a_n$ is not enough as that just implies (again not quite trivially but by the theorem of Landau-Pringsheim) that $f$ has a singularity at $1$

$f$ is meromorphic -- it's only singularities are poles. @Conrad
